# What's the difference between 'var webApp = { .. }' and 'var webApp = function (){ .. }'

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, modularity

I have been experimenting a lot with modular JS lately and I still wonder if I am writing it "the right way".

For example, if I have a page which has inputs and submit buttons that should display data after submittion (table and graph for example) so I write my code under an IFFE so nothing can  access it, but using an object variable like this:

```
var webApp = { ... }
```

and inside it I cache elements from the DOM, add bind events, and other useful functions.

This is a real code I use for a form that should display a graph, table, and a progress bar when loading data, and all is managed in one object `qwData`:

```
(function() {

    const qwData = {

        // Initialize functions
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        // Cache vars 
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.dataDisplayed      = false;
            this.countUsers         = <?php echo $_SESSION['all_users_count_real']; ?>;
            this.customerMachines   = <?php echo $_SESSION['customer_statistics']['total_machines']; ?>;
            this.$form              = $('#frm');
            this.$alistToolbar      = this.$form.find('.alist-toolbar');
            this.start_date         = this.$form[0][9].value;
            this.end_date           = this.$form[0][10].value;
            this.dateCount          = this.countDays(this.start_date, this.end_date);
            this.show               = document.querySelector('#btn-show');
            this.downloadBtn        = document.querySelector('#download_summary_button');
            this.$dataContainer     = $('#qw-data-container');
            this.$qwTable           = $('#qwtable');
            this.$qwTbody           = this.$qwTable.find('tbody');
            this.$qwTd              = this.$qwTbody.find('td');
            this.qwChart            = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main-chart'));
            this.progressBar        = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
            Object.defineProperty(this, "progress", {
                get: () => {
                   return this.progressPrecent || 0;
                },
                set: (value) => {

                    if( value != this.progressPrecent ) {
                      this.progressPrecent = value;
                      // this.setQwChartProgress(value);
                      this.setProgressBarValue(value);
                      this.setProgressButton(value);
                    }
                }, 
                  configurable: true
            });
            this.qwChartProgress    = this.progress;
        },
        // Bind click events (or any events..)
        bindEvents: function() {

            var that = this;

            // On click "Show" BTN
            this.show.onclick = this.sendData.bind(this);

            // On Change inputs
            this.$form.change(function(){
                that.updateDatesInputs(this);
            });

            // downloadQw
            this.downloadBtn.onclick = this.downloadQw.bind(this);
        },
        downloadQw: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var customer = "<?php echo $_SESSION['company_name']; ?>";
            var filename = customer + "qws_"+ this.start_date + "-" + this.end_date + ".zip";

            $.ajax({
                url: "/aaa/api/download_csv.php",
                method: "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                data: { 
                    customer: customer,
                    filename: filename
                },
                success:function(result){
                if(result.status){
                    window.location.href="/aaa/api/download_csv.php?customer="+customer+"&filename="+filename+"&download=1";
                }
            },
                error:function(){
                }
            })
        },
        setQwChartProgress: function(value){
            if (value != 0) {
                // Show Chart Loading 
                this.qwChart.showLoading({
                    color: (value == 99) ? '#00b0f0' : '#fff',
                    text: value + '%' 
                });
            }
        },
        setProgressButton: function(value){

            if ( value >= 100 || value == 0 ){
                this.show.value     = 'Show';
            }
            else {
                this.show.value     = value +'%';
                // this.show.disabled   = true;
                this.disableShow();
            }
        },
        resetShowButton: function(){
            this.show.value = 'Show';
            this.disableShow();
        },
        disableShow: function(){
            // this.show.style.color = "grey";
            // this.show.disabled   = true;
            this.show.classList.add("isDisabled");
        }, 
        enableShow: function(){
            // this.show.style.color = "#66aa66";
            // this.show.disabled   = false;
            this.show.classList.remove("isDisabled");
        },
        updateDatesInputs: function(){
            this.start_date     = this.$form[0][9].value;
            this.end_date       = this.$form[0][11].value;
            this.dateCount      = this.countDays(this.start_date,this.end_date);
            // this.show.disabled   = false;
            this.enableShow();
            this.removeError();
        },
        removeError: function(){
            if (this.errors) {
                this.errors.remove();
                delete this.errors;
            }
        },
        countDays: function(date1, date2){

            // First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
            var date1 = date1.split('-');
            var date2 = date2.split('-');

            // Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
            date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1], date1[2]);
            date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);

            // We use the getTime() method and get the unixtime (in milliseconds, but we want seconds, therefore we divide it through 1000)
            var date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime() / 1000);
            var date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);

            // This is the calculated difference in seconds
            var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;

            // in Hours
            var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;

            // and finaly, in days :)
            var timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours  / 24;

            if (timeDifferenceInDays > 0){
                return timeDifferenceInDays;
            } else {
                // alert('Error: The date are invalid.');
            }
        },
        // Get data, prevent submit defaults and submit. 
        sendData: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (this.show.classList.contains('isDisabled')) {

                this.showErrorDiv("Please select a new date range before submitting.");
            } else {

                let that                = this;
                let estimatedTotalTime  = ( (this.countUsers*this.customerMachines)/777 ) * 0.098; 
                let estimatedTime       = estimatedTotalTime/99;
                let estimatedTimeMs     = estimatedTime*1000;
                let timer               = setInterval( function(){that.incrementProgress(timer);}, estimatedTime); 

                console.log('Total Time: ' + estimatedTotalTime + 's');
                console.log('Estimated Time for 1%: ' + estimatedTime + 's');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/manageit/ajax.php?module=qw_module",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                            start_ts: that.start_date,
                            stop_ts: that.end_date, 
                            submitted: true, 
                            company_name: "<?php echo $_SESSION['company_name']; ?>"
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {

                        // Show Chart Loading 
                        that.qwChart.showLoading({ 
                            color: '#00b0f0', 
                            // text: that.qwChartProgress
                            text: ''
                        });

                        // If data div isn't displayed
                        if (!that.dataDisplayed) {
                            // Show divs loading
                            that.showMainDiv();
                        } else {
                            that.$qwTbody.slideUp('fast');
                            that.$qwTbody.html('');
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function(){},
                    success: function(result){

                        // Reset show btn
                        that.resetShowButton();

                        // Clear timer
                        clearInterval(timer);

                        // Set progressbar to 100%
                        that.setProgressBarTo100();

                        // Show Download Button
                        that.downloadBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';

                        // Insert Chart Data
                        that.insertChartData(result);

                        // Insert Table Data
                        that.insertTableData(result);
                    }
                });

                that.dataDisplayed = true;
            }
        },
        showErrorDiv: function(errorTxt){

            if (!this.errors){
                this.errors             = document.createElement("div");
                this.errors.className   = "qw_errors_div";
                this.errors.textContent = errorTxt;
                this.$alistToolbar.append(this.errors);
            } 
        },
        // Insert Data to Table
        insertTableData: function(json){

            let str = '';
            let isOdd = ' rowspan="2" ';

            for ( let i=1; i<9; i++ ) {

                str += '<tr>';

                for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                    if ((i%2 === 0) && (j==0)){
                        // do nada
                    } else {
                        str += '<td '; 
                        str += ((i % 2 !== 0)&&(j==0)) ? isOdd : '';
                        str += '> '; 
                        str += json[i][j]; 
                        str += '</td>';
                    }
                }
                str += '</tr>'; 
            }

            this.$qwTbody.html(str);

            this.$qwTbody.slideDown('fast', function(){
                if ($(this).is(':visible'))
                    $(this).css('display','table-row-group');
            });

            // Apply colors on table.
            this.tableHover();
        },
        tableHover: function(){

            this.$qwTd              = this.$qwTbody.find('td');
            var that =  this;

            this.$qwTd.eq(0).hover( function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(0).css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(0).parent().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(0).parent().next().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');    
            }, function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(0).css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(0).parent().css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(0).parent().next().css('background-color', '');   
            });

            this.$qwTd.eq(15).hover( function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(15).css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(15).parent().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(15).parent().next().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');   
            }, function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(15).css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(15).parent().css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(15).parent().next().css('background-color', '');  
            });

            this.$qwTd.eq(30).hover( function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(30).css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(30).parent().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(30).parent().next().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');   
            }, function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(30).css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(30).parent().css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(30).parent().next().css('background-color', '');  
            });

            this.$qwTd.eq(45).hover( function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(45).css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(45).parent().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
                that.$qwTd.eq(45).parent().next().css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');   
            }, function(){
                that.$qwTd.eq(45).css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(45).parent().css('background-color', '');
                that.$qwTd.eq(45).parent().next().css('background-color', '');  
            });
        },
        incrementProgress: function(timer){

            if (this.progress == 99)
                clearInterval(timer);
            else 
                this.progress++;
        },
        // Insert Data to Chart
        insertChartData: function(json){

            var posList = [
                'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom',
                'inside',
                'insideTop', 'insideLeft', 'insideRight', 'insideBottom',
                'insideTopLeft', 'insideTopRight', 'insideBottomLeft', 'insideBottomRight'
            ];

            this.qwChart.configParameters = {
                rotate: {
                    min: -90,
                    max: 90
                },
                align: {
                    options: {
                        left: 'left',
                        center: 'center',
                        right: 'right'
                    }
                },
                verticalAlign: {
                    options: {
                        top: 'top',
                        middle: 'middle',
                        bottom: 'bottom'
                    }
                },
                position: {
                    options: echarts.util.reduce(posList, function (map, pos) {
                        map[pos] = pos;
                        return map;
                    }, {})
                },
                distance: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100
                }
            };

            this.qwChart.config = {
                rotate: 90,
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                position: 'insideBottom',
                distance: 15,
                onChange: function () {
                    var labelOption = {
                        normal: {
                            rotate: this.qwChart.config.rotate,
                            align: this.qwChart.config.align,
                            verticalAlign: this.qwChart.config.verticalAlign,
                            position: this.qwChart.config.position,
                            distance: this.qwChart.config.distance
                        }
                    };
                    this.qwChart.setOption({
                        series: [{
                            label: labelOption
                        }, {
                            label: labelOption
                        }, {
                            label: labelOption
                        }]
                    });
                }
            };

            var labelOption = {
                normal: {
                    show: true,
                    position: this.qwChart.config.position,
                    distance: this.qwChart.config.distance,
                    align: this.qwChart.config.align,
                    verticalAlign: this.qwChart.config.verticalAlign,
                    rotate: this.qwChart.config.rotate,
                    // formatter: '{c}  {name|{a}}',
                    formatter: '{name|{a}}',
                    fontSize: 16,
                    rich: {
                        name: {
                            // textBorderColor: '#fff', 
                            // color: '#333',
                            // color: '#717171',
                            color: '#525252',
                            shadowColor: 'transparent', 
                            shadowBlur: 0, 
                            textBorderColor: 'transparent',
                            textBorderWidth: 0, 
                            textShadowColor: 'transparent', 
                            textShadowBlur: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            option = {
                color: ['#007bff', '#00b0f0', 'red', '#e5323e'],
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: 'axis',
                    axisPointer: {
                        type: 'shadow'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    data: ['Inactives / Viewers', 'Inactives / Viewers / Less than 1min per day', 'Light no Macro'] 
                },
                toolbox: {
                    show: true,
                    orient: 'vertical',
                    left: 'right',
                    top: 'center',
                    feature: {
                        mark: {show: true},
                        // dataView: {show: true, readOnly: false},
                        // magicType: {show: true, type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack', 'tiled']},
                        restore: {show: true},
                        saveAsImage: {show: true}
                    }
                },
                calculable: true,
                xAxis: [
                    {
                        type: 'category',
                        axisTick: {show: false},
                        data: ['Excel', 'Word', 'PowerPoint', 'All 3 Apps']
                    }
                ],
                yAxis: [
                    {
                        type: 'value', 
                        name: 'Score'
                    }
                ],
                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Light no Macro',
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: labelOption,
                        color: 'red',
                        data: [ [3, json[7][7]] ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Inactives / Viewers',
                        type: 'bar',
                        barGap: 0,
                        label: labelOption,
                        data: [ json[1][7], json[3][7], json[5][7], json[8][7] ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Inactives / Viewers / Less than 1min per day',
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: labelOption,
                        data: [ json[2][7], json[4][7], json[6][7] ]
                    }
                ]
            };

            // Set charts options
            this.qwChart.setOption(option);
            // Hide Loading
            this.qwChart.hideLoading();
        },
        // Show Main div on submition (only)
        showMainDiv: function(){
            // Show all contatner div
            this.$dataContainer.slideDown('slow');
        },
        // Sets a new value for the progress bar
        setProgressBarValue: function(value){

            this.progressBar.style.width = this.returnNumWithPrecent(value);
        },
        returnNumWithPrecent: function(num){

            return num.toString() + '%';
        },
        setProgressBarTo100: function(){
            var that = this;
            // Show Download Button
            this.progress = 100;
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Show Download Button
                that.progress = 0;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    // run object
    qwData.init();
})();
```

but I see [other examples](https://medium.com/@jrschwane/writing-modular-javascript-pt-2-d7140d15c982) that write the functionality under a function and not an object:

```
webApp = function (){ ... };
```

like the example:

```
var Background = (function() {
  'use strict';
  // placeholder for cached DOM elements
  var DOM = {};
  /* =================== private methods ================= */
  // cache DOM elements
  function cacheDom() {
    DOM.$background = $('#background');
  }

  // coordinate async assembly of image element and rendering
  function loadImage() {
    var baseUrl = 'https://source.unsplash.com/category',
        cat     = 'nature',
        size    = '1920x1080';
    buildElement(`${baseUrl}/${cat}/${size}`)
      .then(render);
  }

  // assemble the image element
  function buildElement(source) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(function (task) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function () {
        task.resolve(image);
      };
      image.onerror = function () {
        task.reject();
      };
      image.src = source;
    });
    return deferred.promise();
  }

  // render DOM
  function render(image) { 
    DOM.$background
      .append(image)
      .css('opacity', 1);
  }

  /* =================== public methods ================== */
  // main init method
  function init() {
    cacheDom();
    loadImage();
  }

  /* =============== export public methods =============== */
  return {
    init: init
  };
}());
```

I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. What is the difference between using an object and inside of it setting functions, vars, ect':

   var webApp = { ... };

and a function variable with the same characteristics (just with a
    syntax written differently). like the example from the link I pasted.

```
var webApp = function (){ ... };
```

2. Is this right to write code like that where all (kinda separated elements like the graph, table, progress-bar) in one object/function? Should this be better separated to different objects? If there is a newer better way to write such code please mention what I should research.

Comment: I am unclear on what you are asking. Since this is how people achieved 'modules' circa 2012, are you asking about historical usage or whether you should do any of this today? Note also that your examples are not strictly equivalent to each other.

Comment: @JaredSmith `Since this is how people achieved 'modules' circa 2012, are you asking about historical usage or whether you should do any of this today?` I  have just started exploring modular JS and this is what i learned via tutorials I have found, if there is a better / newer way to write this kind of code, that i even dont know of - I would be more than happy  if you can tell me what to research. My final aim is to know how to code something like i mentioned.

Comment: @RickSanchez I wrote probably more than you wanted to know :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems with internet tutorials is that they linger past the point of relevance and very few authors keep them up to date. Things move exceedingly quickly in JS land and an industry standard from 5 years ago (e.g. jQuery) now seems odd when you still stumble across it.

So, to put into practice the good habit that I'm nagging on others for omitting:

### State of JavaScript Modules, Mid 2018, changing fast, #deprecated

It's a mess.

First you have ES 6 modules. ES 6 was renamed to ES 2015 and the modules part was taken out and made into a separate spec, meaning that a browser could be ES 2015 compliant and still not have native modules. However, 3 years later, every browser with a relevant global market share (chrome, android chrome, firefox, iOS Safari) implements at least a basic version of the native module system (so do Edge, Opera, etc.). I am unclear since I believe the spec allows paths to be more forgiving (we'll get back to that in a minute), but here is the syntax, relative or absolute filepath with extension required:

```
import Foo from './foo.js'; // Import default export from foo.js, alias to 'Foo'
import { Foo } from './foo.js'; // Import named export 'Foo' from foo.js

export default function () {}; // exports a function as default, importer aliases
const Foo = class Foo {};
export Foo; // exports named class Foo
```

These have a lot of advantages over anything else (first and foremost you don't need special tools or build processes), but because they are *very* recent they aren't in super widespread use in the JavaScript ecosystem yet. Because they were long in coming, and people had work to get done, they implemented various other module patterns/tools/systems. One of the earliest ones is the one in your question, but that pattern while certainly better than nothing has enough problems that people started looking around.

#### AMD modules

One other earlier offering was `require.js`'s asynchronous module definition. While it had some compelling technical advantages, it is effectively dead.

#### Common.js modules

node.js exploded on to the scene with it's own module system based on common.js modules (that basically have become the defacto flavor of common.js). People started saying "hey it'd be great to be able to do this in the browser too" and thus, browserify. Browserify was a tool that would traverse your dependency graph and convert `require` expressions into something the browser could handle (basically, by making require a function). Node's modules are kinda ill-suited to the browser, but converging on one standard was better than eighty million competing adhoc implementations. People looked at these three competing module patterns/systems (one in your question, AMD, common.js) and said hey we can unify these. Thus

#### Universal module definition

If you've seen code in the wild that looks like this:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // Node, CommonJS-like
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals (root is window)
        root.returnExports = factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function ($) {
```

Then you've seen UMD. Note how it checks to see if the environment it's in is set up for AMD or common.js. Transformers were written to convert both styles to this for legacy code and legibility concerns (that's a fair bit of boilerplate).

But people wanted more: they wanted to be able to express *all* of their webapp's dependencies (including css and images) in code, with a tool to shard and selectively load it. Plus by this time the native module spec was in draft and people wanted to use that syntax. And thus

#### Webpack modules

Webpack is currently the defacto system in use today (although lots of people still use browserify). Webpack's module syntax looks something like this:

```
import Foo from 'foo'; // imports default export from foo.js somewhere on PATH
```

Does that look familiar? Very similar to (yet subtly different from the native modules). Webpack can also do the following:

```
import 'Something.css'; // commonly seen in react apps
import 'logo.svg'; // ditto
```

This is handy, as people move to componentized systems, it's nice to be able to express all component dependencies in an entry point file for that component. Unfortunately HTML imports which would have allowed you to do that natively without a build step died a flaming horrible death.

The incompatibilities with the native module system, subtle (path and file extensions) and gross (importing non-js assets) are unfortunate, it means that one or the other is going to have to change because I've tried to write native module-based apps recently and it is *very* hard to consume libraries (almost none of which offer a native module flavor).

What to use is a kind of opinionated question, but if you're using a framework use whatever is common for other users of that framework. Common.js and webpack are common enough that there are plenty of tools for consuming them and are probably your best bet at this moment. The other thing to watch for are dynamic imports, already landed in several browsers.

Sorry this is all so confusing, you just happen to be entering JavaScript during a very transitional time.

Comment: I might be a little bit more confused. What you're saying is that whatever I wrote in my post is "not relevant" for todays javascript, and I should learn ES 6 (which is the same as ES 2015? I understand correctly?) which is written differently (has classes as "class" syntaxes ect and not as vanilla js functions/objects). What should be my learning flow now? If my knowledge is based on the code pasted in the main post.. I should learn writing ES6? or how to use webpack first? I use PHP mainly, and don't want to learn nodejs, is nodejs necessary?

Comment: @RickSanchez if you want my opinion (something I tried to avoid in my answer) about what you should use to get work done *today*, use webpack. As for the code in your question, the *techniques* are relevant (e.g. IIFEs, closures) but using them to implement modules is not. Understanding of node.js is not required (pun intended) but if you see `var foo = require('foo');` then that's where that came from even if some code transformer rewrites it for the front end. As for *why* we don't use the module pattern like in your code anymore, that's an entire new question but the short answer is...

Comment: ...(cont'd) what about circular dependencies? Name conflicts? Lazy loading? Bundling/sharding? Static analysis? It turns out there's a lot of things you actually want in a real module system and using IIFEs just doesn't cut it.

Comment: So I'll search for a decent webpack + ES6 (+bable?) online course for the weekend i guess

Comment: @RickSanchez good plan. Writing lowest-common-denominator JavaScript is tedious, many of us use the latest standardized stuff and rely on tools like babel and webpack, with things like gulp (or even good old Make) to tie it all together. Note that these are tools for professional developers to build production customer-facing sites, if you're not looking to play the game at that level (which is totally fine) then you likely don't need modules *at all*.

Comment: It's just weird, its like a total different JS. btw, if there is any online course you recommend on.. i'll be happy to consider checking out.

Comment: @RickSanchez that's because JS was invented in 10 days in 1995 to add 10 lines of behavior to mostly static pages. Now that people routinely have 50KLoC JS codebases we've had to make changes. PHP actually has it even worse: include and require are very thin wrappers over the underlying C constructs and make it quite difficult to avoid e.g. name conflicts (caveat, my PHP knowledge stops at about 5.3 they might have fixed it in PHP 7+ although I doubt it). AFAIK, PHP only offers class-based object oriented "solutions".

Comment: I don't necessarily know one off the top of my head but after a quick google [this](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/) looks pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The IIFE pattern allows for private variables - `DOM`, `cacheDom`, `loadImage` - which aren’t accessible from outside the IIFE. In the object pattern, everything is accessible publically as properties of the object. Sometimes you can’t construct the object you want at all without declaring some variables first, so keeping those isolated inside an IIFE is useful too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with object oriented programming it could be understood through the analogy of private and public properties and functions of a class.
Other approach: modular pattern, see node modules. It is about packaging.

Look at this code:

```
var obj = (function() {
    let a = function() { console.log('function a'); };
    let b = function() { a(); console.log('function b'); };
    return { b: b };
})();

obj.b();
// function a
// function b

obj.a();
// TypeError: obj.a is not a function
```

Or maybe more familiar in this way:

```
function MyStuff() {
    let a = function() { console.log('function a'); };
    let b = function() { a(); console.log('function b'); };
    return { b: b };
}

var obj = MyStuff();

obj.b();
// function a
// function b

obj.a();
// TypeError: obj.a is not a function
```

Inside a function, you have a local scope, not accessible from the outside. in this local scope, you create variables, functions, etc.

In the return statement, you return an object exporting functions, and variables to the outer scope. It is like deciding which functions/props to be public, which should stay private.

When you are creating object in the `var webApp = {...}` way, you are directly creating an object, with all of its props and functions being public to the scope you are defining variable "webApp".

Answering your second question, yes, you should separate stuff into separate objects by concerns. See SOLID principles. :)

Comment: I am familiar with OOP, just not it javascript, I don't understand how this is the difference between `var webApp = function (){ .. }` that looks like your first example to `var webApp = { .. }` - i do understand your examples but don't know how it is relevant to my question, maybe im missing something and not understanding you well

Comment: You're right, not covered the whole question. I'm updating the answer. :)

Comment: And if I put my object under an IFFE like the `qwData = { .. }` example, does this solve the privacy issue? (if yes, how is it different from writing it the way you explained, and which is better / when to use each of the cases)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but take a look at `MyStuff` function. It returns an object referencing only function b publicly. So only b is accessible directly through `obj`. If I've created variable obj like `var obj = {a: function(){...}, b: function(){...}}` both a and b could be accessible. For encapsulation it's better to use constructors, for code reuse also, since you can call MyStuff anytime you want, without the need for defining it's properties/functions all over again.